# Common way to access data from Windows, Android & iOS

Tags: android, ios, windows

We have a desktop application on Windows. We want to bring the same application to Android and iPhone.
Some of data are in SQL format while other are stored in text files.
We want to build a common library using which we can access the sql data and text data in Windows, Android and iOS using C/C++. Will it work on all these platforms?

Comment: Exposing data through webservices would be the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

You want to be using OData to expose these through a WCF Service. Then call the WCF Service from the applications from the devices to bring back the data you need.